# Logos of known brands

Tags: website-design, licenses

Where do webmasters find logos to use on their websites? I mean, I have a product that is compatible with Windows, Linux, Java, NodeJS, SQLs etc etc... I would like to use their logos somewhere on my site. Is there anything that a lot of people use? Can I just grab it from, f.e. Linux website? I think it's rather not permitted. Do I have to "paint" everything on my own?
Please advice.

Comment: Sorry but this question is opinionated and recommendations on resources are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Google image search, do a search for [brand name] .png to find the logo and read the website terms of service to see if you can use it. That is what I would do.